# Where should I call API's validate() endpoint when implementing Terraform Provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm working on creating a new Terraform Provider using [Terraform Plugin SDKv2](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2).

I read [the tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/providers/provider-create) but I still have a question.

Imagine my API resource `Foo` has got a generic CRUD API and also a validate API endpoint.

I can use that validate endpoint to check that creation request is valid meaning my request won't return `400` status code for `CREATE / POST` request.

My initial thinking was I could call it in `resourceCreate()`:

```
func fooRead(...) {}
func fooCreate(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
  // err := client.Validate(request)
  // if err != nil { return diag.Errrof("error validating request") }
  ...
  // foo = client.Create(request)
}
```

That's a great start, however I noticed that it only works during `terraform apply` and doesn't work during `terraform plan`.

Is there a way to call `client.Validate(request)` in a different place such that it'll be called during `terraform plan` phase?

I searched a little bit and managed to find [CustomizeDiff](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences) method. Is it a good idea to move it there?

Comment: If you upgrade to the plugin framework, then you can create arbitrary validation functions and utilize them within each resource `struct` for the parameters' validation. That being said: it would probably be easier in both SDKv2 and plugin framework to validate on parameters individually instead of the request as that would also trigger during `validate` earlier in the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform's model the "validate" call is intended only for static validation based on rules hard-coded into the provider plugin. Validation is done using an *unconfigured* instance of the provider -- that is, the provider doesn't yet know any values from the associated `provider` block -- and so it cannot contact a remote API to perform validation.

The plan phase *is* a good place to do "online" validation like this, though.

If you intend to continue using the legacy plugin SDK then [`CustomizeDiff`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences) is indeed that SDK's way of hooking in to the plan phase. That function is named after its possibility to change the values included in Terraform's plan, but it's also fine for it to just return an error declaring that something in the configuration is invalid.

The equivalent to that in the modern plugin framework would be [Plan Modification](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification), with a plan modify implementation that [returns error diagnostics](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification#resource-destroy-plan-diagnostics) when the given configuration is invalid.